# How to create objects from jsons in python with a complex constructor?

Tags: python, json, object, constructor, namedtuple

I am trying to create a blockchain and need a function to put my Blocks into json format and be able to create objects again. This seems quite difficult, since my constructor does not take all the attributes as parameters. My constructor looks like this:

```
class Block:

    id = 0

    def __init__(self, transaction, prevhash):
        self.transactions  = []         
        self.transactions.append(transaction)
        self.prevhash = prevhash        
        self.timestamp = time.time()    
        self.id = Block.id          
        Block.id = Block.id + 1
```

I encode them the following (which seems to work perfectly fine):

```
    def to_json(self):
        return json.dumps(self, indent=4, cls=BlockEncoder)

class BlockEncoder(JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        return o.__dict__
```

It creates that output for me (just an example):

```
{
    "transactions": [
        {
            "ipfshash": 1,
            "title": null,
            "length": null,
            "id": 0
        },
        {
            "ipfshash": 3,
            "title": null,
            "length": null,
            "id": 2
        }
    ],
    "prevhash": 10,
    "timestamp": 1591350715.1794589,
    "id": 0
}
```

What im trying now to get it into an object again is (i need a generator like object to call the function, but it works. Still trying to figure out how i can make that one static :D)

```
    def from_json(self, jsondict):
        return json.loads(jsondict, object_hook=custom_block_decoder)

def custom_block_decoder(jsondict):
    return namedtuple('Block', jsondict.keys())(*jsondict.values())
```

So, if I do that with some element and print it, it wont use my defined `__str__` function, also I cant call any other function of my Block class. It seems that `namedtuple('Block', jsondict.keys())(*jsondict.values())` just names my object type "Block" but does not really apply anything to it to make it an object. I can call element.attribute, but cant call for element.to_json() again, since the error message is `AttributeError: 'Block' object has no attribute 'to_json'`. I thought about decoding it per hand, but since I cant use multiple constructors that does not seem a good idea. Would be great if somebody could help me

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `namedtuple`?

> It seems that `namedtuple('Block', jsondict.keys())(*jsondict.values())`
>   just names my object type "Block" but does not really apply anything to it to make it an object.

Everything is an object. `namedtuple` is a factory function that creates a **subclass of `tuple`** that supports named attribute access, but *it is still a `tuple`*. I'm not sure why would you *expect* it to be an instance of the custom `Block` class that you defined. It doesn't make much sense to use it here.

In any case, you have to write the deserialization routine yourself. In general, this would look something like

```
class Foo:

    def __init__(self, bar):
        self.bar = bar
        self.baz = 42

    def frobnicate(self):
        baz = self.baz
        self.baz = self.baz ** 2 // 4

    @classmethod
    def from_dict(cls, dict_foo):
        foo = cls.__new__(cls) # just object.__new__
        # here is where you have to implement the logic yourself to rebuild your object. 
        # hopefully it doesn't get too complex
        foo.__dict__.update(dict_foo)
        return foo
```

Note, using a classmethod is customary, then you can use

```
Foo.from_dict({'bar': 8, 'baz': 42})
```

And it plays a bit better with inheritance. These sorts of classmethods are usually referred to as *alternative constructors*.

Comment: Thank you, i got it right now :) I actually never really worked in python and just google for the stuff i need therefore i dont really know how some specific things work.